# If one asked Shenron or Porunga to kill Kami/Dende/Guru/Moori, would they be able to do so?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

We know the dragons are limited by the power of their creators - so, if you were to ask them to kill someone stronger than their creator, they would be unable to do so. However, is there a canonical answer to whether or not they can kill someone just as strong as them, such as their creators themselves?

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion-based. Either there's a canon answer or there isn't, in which case the answer is "we don't know". Voting to reopen.

Comment: I don't know if I can vote to reopen my own question or if I have enough rep, but I vote to reopen

Comment: Hint: They intended to ask him to fight Piccolo Daimaô in Dragon Ball. The hypothetical fight would have been fair, even if Kami was later on revealed to be much stronger than the original Piccolo. But Piccolo killed Shenron before they could do that. Dende, on the other hand, isn't a fighter.